Can a table of results be returned and formatted as a table in Agentforce when an Apex @InvocableMethod is used?
I'm using a scratch org that has the feature Einstein1AIPlatform and enableEinsteinGptPlatform set to true.
I have this Apex code:
@InvocableMethod(
    label='List documents related to records'
    description='List documents related to the named Fund including those related to its child records.'
)
public static Response[] listDocuments(Request[] requests) {
    ...
}

that is invoked by the agent with the debug log showing it completes and returns. But whatever instruction I've tried to format the output e.g. 'The "Documents" variable holds an array of objects that have variables such as "Title" and "Size" that should be presented as rows of a table' I get the 'We couldn't retrieve the action output' error shown in the screen shot below. The Apex class is included in the Einstein User profile.
The returned (inner) classes are these:
global inherited sharing class Response {

    @InvocableVariable(label='Documents')
    public Document[] documents = new Document[] {};
}

global inherited sharing class Document {

    @InvocableVariable(label='Content Version Id')
    public Id contentVersionId;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Title')
    public String title;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Size')
    public Integer size;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Created Date')
    public Datetime createdDate;
}

that appear compatible with the specification of an @InvocableMethod. The first level is a response for each request and then within the response the second level is the array of records to show as a table.
Does Agentforce have this ability? What pattern is needed to make it work? (Also asked here.)

PS
A JSON.serializePretty of the returned Response[] from immediately before the return:
[ {
  "documents" : [ {
    "title" : "Agenda",
    "size" : 828,
    "createdDate" : "2024-12-20T13:05:47.000Z",
    "contentVersionId" : "068Oy000009lyraIAA"
  }, {
    "title" : "Sales",
    "size" : 324296,
    "createdDate" : "2024-12-19T11:48:03.000Z",
    "contentVersionId" : "068Oy000009kOS0IAM"
  } ]
} ]

PPS
The Event Log consistently shows this message-less error:


Where you able to get debug logs and see if the Apex is being called or not?

Hi @MohithShrivastava, Yes the Apex is running and I also dumped data just before the return as JSON and it looked as I would expect. Are there any examples in GitHub I could take a look at?

Can you give an example of what your response looks like so I can try reproducing this error?

Thanks @MohithShrivastava; I've added that to the question.

This is a bug. So definitely you should raise a support ticket for it.
Having said that this can be workaround easily by doing some prompting as a part of Action instruction as shown below

Here is a simple class that did repro your error but I added bit more prompting to fix it
global inherited sharing class DocumentService {

global class Response {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Documents' description='List of Document objects containing details about each document')
    public Document[] documents = new Document[] {};
}

global class Document {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Content Version Id' description='The unique identifier for the content version of the document')
    public Id contentVersionId;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Title' description='The title or name of the document')
    public String title;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Size' description='The size of the document in bytes')
    public Integer size;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Created Date' description='The date and time when the document was created')
    public Datetime createdDate;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Get Document Responses' description='Returns document details for the given document names')
public static List<Response> getDocumentsResponse(List<String> documentNames) {
    List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();

    for (String docName : documentNames) {
        Response response = new Response();
        List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();

        // Creating multiple Document objects for each input name (example data)
        for (Integer i = 1; i <= 2; i++) { // Generating two documents per response
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.contentVersionId = Id.valueOf('068Oy000009lyraIAA'.substring(0, 15 - i.toString().length()) + i.toString()); // Unique ID for each doc
            doc.title = docName + ' - Version ' + i;
            doc.size = Math.mod(docName.length() * 100 * i, 500000); // Example size calculation
            doc.createdDate = Datetime.now().addDays(-Math.mod(docName.length() * i, 30)); // Example created date
            documents.add(doc);
        }

        // Assigning the documents array to the response
        response.documents = documents;

        // Adding the response to the list
        responses.add(response);
    }

    // Returning the list of responses
    return responses;
   }
 }



Thanks Mohith. I've copied your prompts and annotated by Apex as your have and tried some variations and still no success. Is it possible that my scratch org environment (see start of question) is using different a different version of Agentforce?

Definitely possible..It must be that..Try in probably other environments
